# Language set on Facebook Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, button

I'm trying to change the language of my facebook buttons for my web. I changed

```
//connect.facebook.net/en_US
```

to

```
//connect.facebook.net/es_ES
```

but nothing happend ¿can somebody help me?

my web is http://goo.gl/nqQnts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the language in the url of your iframe!

Comment: I have not control of the iframe, it be generated from this div:

Comment: <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/webpagename" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>

Comment: Change it in the JS code you copied from facebook. Search for this line: js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/

Comment: I can't found it. I have now like this //connect.facebook.net/es_ES

Comment: should be correct? The code facebook told you to put it right after opening the <body> tag

Comment: Fixed! I had a plugin that create another js with en_En languaje definition. I edited plugin and works!